# How to render timeseries/categorical stacked bar chart in dc.js, filtering stack and bar

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Most examples I have found are using data that has time and number

```
var data =      [
  {
    "Time": "19-Jan-2018 11:24:49.000 UTC",
    "Speed": 1.885
  },
  {
    "Time": "19-Jan-2018 11:24:59.000 UTC",
    "Speed": 1.875
  },
  {
    "Time": "19-Jan-2018 11:25:00.000 UTC",
    "Speed": 1.878
  },
  {
    "Time": "19-Jan-2018 11:25:01.000 UTC",
    "Speed": 1.876
  }
]
```

I am looking to stack type

```
    var data =      [
  {
    "Time": "19-Jan-2018 11:24:49.000 UTC",
    "type": "CAT"
  },
  {
    "Time": "19-Jan-2018 11:24:59.000 UTC",
    "type": "DOG"
  },
  {
    "Time": "19-Jan-2018 11:25:00.000 UTC",
    "type": "CAT"
  },
  {
    "Time": "19-Jan-2018 11:25:01.000 UTC",
    "Type": "BAT"
  }
]
```

How can I stack categorical data, while allowing the user to select time/category pairs, as in the following [Example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/filter-stacks.html)?

Comment: I take it you want to count the number of each type? Seems like [this example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/stacked-bar.html) would be a better place to start, just using `1` instead of `v.Speed`. However, yes it is more complicated if you want to select the individual stacks within a bar as the example you linked. So please confirm you want that as well?

Comment: I tried with adding 1 to it, instead of d.speed. but the chart comes out blank no errors nothing. also, I am using dc.js v1.7.5 cant upgrade @Gordon

Comment: Also I would like to have filtering options like the example I gave

Comment: It's hard to say what went wrong without seeing your running code. `p[v.Type] = (p[v.Type] || 0) + 1;` should work. If you want selection of individual stacks, then yes it's pretty complicated because it requires 2D keys. I guess I can work up an example but it seems pretty esoteric to me, so it might take me a few days.

Comment: So what do you suggest I use I am open to using any other chart types that can easily do this @Gordon

Comment: I don’t know of any other charting library that supports this. And it isn’t easy in dc.js.  Like I said, I can work up an example but it’s a considerable effort, so I probably won’t get to it for a few days.

Comment: Sorry, just to confirm one more time: you want to be able to select by date and type, right? So each click will select one date/type pair?

Comment: Thank you for your help @Gordon . [Screen Shot](https://pasteboard.co/IYtTQqo.jpg) This explains the current UI, If you think that other chart types combined like lineChart etc can easily display categorical data. I can also change my chart Type. its not necessary to stick to barChart.

Comment: yes each click will select one date/type pair just like in your [example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/filter-stacks.html) Since I have alot of filters

Comment: There isn’t any way to select an individual point and stack in a line chart (the whole line is a single graphical object), so I think it would have to be a bar chart.

Comment: I edited your question to be more specific. In the future, please include more detail about what you're trying to do. I understood your question only because I wrote that example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adapted the example to time/category data in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/zmo805ps/10/).

Those dates would only parse in Chrome, so

```
const parseDate = d3.utcParse("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S.%L UTC");
data.forEach(d => {
  d.Time = parseDate(d.Time);
})
```

I changed the key functions to use `,`

```
function multikey(x,y) {
  return x + ',' + y;
}
function splitkey(k) {
  return k.split(',');
}
```

I also changed fake group `stack_second` to convert string-dates from the multikeys back into Dates, and to initialize categories to 0 (since every stack has to be present for every X).

```
function stack_second(group, categories) {
  return {
    all: function() {
      var all = group.all(),
          m = {};
      // build matrix from multikey/value pairs
      all.forEach(function(kv) {
        var ks = splitkey(kv.key);
        m[ks[0]] = m[ks[0]] || Object.fromEntries(categories.map(c=>[c,0]));
        m[ks[0]][ks[1]] = kv.value;
      });
      // then produce multivalue key/value pairs
      return Object.keys(m).map(function(k) {
        return {key: new Date(k), value: m[k]};
      });
    }
  };
}
```

Get the array of categories from the source data:

```
const categories = Array.from(new Set(data.map(d => d.Type)).values());
```

When dealing with date/time, you have to choose a [d3 time interval](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#time-intervals-d3-time) appropriate for your data. Here minutes looked right. Using UTC d3-time methods everywhere because your source data is UTC.

```
const interval = d3.utcMinute;
```

Calculate xscale domain and apply:

```
let extent = d3.extent(data, d=>d.Time);
extent[1] = interval.offset(extent[1], 1)
chart
  .x(d3.scaleTime().domain(extent))
  .xUnits(interval.range)
```

Right number of ticks, also formatted in UTC:

```
chart.xAxis().ticks(d3.utcMinute).tickFormat(d3.utcFormat('%H:%M'))
```

Match colors between stacks and wedges with

```
.colors(d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(categories).range(d3.schemeCategory10))
```

Crossfilter initialization, using the interval and categories:

```
const interval = d3.utcMinute; // choose appropriate to your data
var cf = crossfilter(data),
    timeTypeDim = cf.dimension(function(d) { return multikey(interval(d.Time), d.Type); }),
    timeTypeGroup = timeTypeDim.group(), // reduceCount by default
    stackedGroup = stack_second(timeTypeGroup, categories);
```

And here's the chart code for completeness, although we've already discussed the relevant parts:

```
function sel_stack(i) {
  return function(d) {
    return d.value[i];
  };
}
chart
  .width(600)
  .height(400)
  .colors(d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(categories).range(d3.schemeCategory10))

  .controlsUseVisibility(true)
  .x(d3.scaleTime().domain(extent))
  .xUnits(interval.range)
  .margins({left: 80, top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 20})
  .brushOn(false)
  .clipPadding(10)
  .title(function(d) {
  return d.key + '[' + this.layer + ']: ' + d.value[this.layer];
})
  .legend(dc.legend().x(540).y(50))
  .dimension(timeTypeDim)
  .group(stackedGroup, categories[0], sel_stack(categories[0]))
  .renderLabel(true);
```

[image: time/category stacked bars]